# FormData missing a field with Blob once sent to the server

Tags: javascript, fetch, form-data

I'm trying to send some JSON data along with an image to the server. The image `Blob` is coming from canvas' `toBlob` method which I wrapped into a simple `Promise`:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlobPromise = function ( mimeType, qualityArgument ) {
  let that = this;
  return new Promise ( function ( resolve, reject ) {
    that.toBlob ( function ( blob ) {
      resolve ( blob );
    }, mimeType, qualityArgument );
  });
}
```

This seems to be working fine as I can see the Blob data in the console.

Here's the code where the issue occurs:

```
// preview is a canvas
// doc is an object literal

return preview.toBlobPromise ( 'image/png', 0.8 )
.then ( blob => {

  let data = new FormData();
  data.append( 'doc', JSON.stringify ( doc ) );
  data.append( 'preview', blob );

  // log all fields

  for ( let field of data ) {
    console.log ( field );
  }

  // at this point, both fields are logged correctly
  // (2) ["doc", "{my JSON data}"]
  // (2) ["preview", File(388719)]

  return fetch ( 'save.php', {
    body : data,
    method : 'POST'
  })
})
.then ( response => response.text() )
.then ( text => {

  console.log ( text );

  // here however, all I get is the 'doc' field
  // array(1) {
  //   ["doc"]=> my JSON data
  // }


})
```

On the server side save.php only contains `var_dump ( $_POST )`.

Comment: Files are not included in php's `$_POST` superglobal, they have their own

Comment: @PatrickEvans Simple fix, it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Patrick Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560593/patrick-evans) said, the `$_POST` superglobal does not contain files - they are stored in the `$_FILES` superglobal.